# Difference in prologue function

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I'm reading *Haching: the art of exploitation* and I have found a difference in my compiled code and the one in the book.

The code:

```
void test_function(int a, int b, int c, int d) {

   int flag;
   char buffer[10];

   flag = 31337;
   buffer[0] = 'A';
}

int main() {

   test_function(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

In the book he compiles with gcc and disassembles with gdb, I don't know the version of the softwares.
He uses the commands:

```
gcc -g program.c
gdb -q ./a.out
```

Then he does:

```
(gdb) disass main 
Dump of assembler code for function main(): 
0x08048357 <main+0>:    push   ebp 
0x08048358 <main+1>:    mov    ebp,esp 
0x0804835a <main+3>:    sub    esp,0x18 
0x0804835d <main+6>:    and    esp,0xfffffff0 
0x08048360 <main+9>:    mov    eax,0x0 
0x08048365 <main+14>:   sub    esp,eax 
0x08048367 <main+16>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+12],0x4 
0x0804836f <main+24>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+8],0x3 
0x08048377 <main+32>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+4],0x2 
0x0804837f <main+40>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x1 
0x08048386 <main+47>:   call   0x8048344 <test_function> 
0x0804838b <main+52>:   leave  
0x0804838c <main+53>:   ret    

End of assembler dump
(gdb) disass test_function() 
Dump of assembler code for function test_function: 
0x08048344 <test_function+0>:   push   ebp 
0x08048345 <test_function+1>:   mov    ebp,esp 
0x08048347 <test_function+3>:   sub    esp,0x28 
0x0804834a <test_function+6>:   mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-12],0x7a69 
0x08048351 <test_function+13>:  mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-40],0x41 
0x08048355 <test_function+17>:  leave  
0x08048356 <test_function+18>:  ret
```

Instead this is my output (using the same command):

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000000000040058b <+0>: push   rbp
   0x000000000040058c <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000000000040058f <+4>: mov    ecx,0x4
   0x0000000000400594 <+9>: mov    edx,0x3
   0x0000000000400599 <+14>:    mov    esi,0x2
   0x000000000040059e <+19>:    mov    edi,0x1
   0x00000000004005a3 <+24>:    call   0x400546 <test_function>
   0x00000000004005a8 <+29>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000004005ad <+34>:    pop    rbp
   0x00000000004005ae <+35>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.

(gdb) disass test_function 
Dump of assembler code for function test_function:
   0x0000000000400546 <+0>: push   rbp
   0x0000000000400547 <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000000000040054a <+4>: sub    rsp,0x40
   0x000000000040054e <+8>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x34],edi
   0x0000000000400551 <+11>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x38],esi
   0x0000000000400554 <+14>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x3c],edx
   0x0000000000400557 <+17>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x40],ecx
   0x000000000040055a <+20>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x0000000000400563 <+29>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
   0x0000000000400567 <+33>:    xor    eax,eax
   0x0000000000400569 <+35>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x24],0x7a69
   0x0000000000400570 <+42>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0x20],0x41
   0x0000000000400574 <+46>:    nop
   0x0000000000400575 <+47>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   0x0000000000400579 <+51>:    xor    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x0000000000400582 <+60>:    je     0x400589 <test_function+67>
   0x0000000000400584 <+62>:    call   0x400420 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
   0x0000000000400589 <+67>:    leave  
   0x000000000040058a <+68>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

I'm using gcc version  5.4.0 and gdb version 7.11.1.

I have two question:

- Why is the function proloque different? What's the difference in the instructions given by the book compiler and the ones given by mine ? (I am not talking about the name of the register, I'm talking about why my main prologue does just push and move)
- Could the difference in test_function due to a possible stack overflow and the compiler (that is newer than the other one) knows and patches it ? If so, how does it knows that a flaw exists and what method does it employ to patches it?

**EDIT**:  I know the book version was compiled on a 32 bit architecture. My question was about the different instruction of the compiler, if they have to do the same things, why are they different?

Comment: Compiler change with time, and GCC in particular updates frequently enough to not produce necessarily the same code across versions. You version is most probably newer that what the author used to write the book.

Comment: You're compiling for x86-64, the book compiles for x86 (32-bit).

Comment: In response to your edit the reason they are different between 64-bit and 32-bit is because the calling convention is different. The other difference is that you are using a different compiler than what is in the book and it is also building stack checking in (not uncommon if you are using later versions of Debian or Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

The book version was compiled on a 32 bit architecture, your one on 64. Use the `-m32` switch to generate 32 bit executable.

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear. I know the book version was compiled on a 32 bit architecture, my question was about the different instruction of the compiler, if they have to do the same things, why are they different?